Mac Dock (bottom launch bar): Remove or hide a specific app only from Recents (when it's closed)
The solutions I find are to hide all recent apps from Dock.
But I want to hide or remove only a specific app, not all recent app.
If I click on Remove from Dock, the app will be back there next time I open and close the app.

Is there any way to hide only specific apps, or the only current way to go is either hide or show all recent apps?

UPDATE:
Adding a file, app or folder to "Spotlight Privacy" will also hide them from the Recents folder.
But the app will keep being shown in the Dock.

Are you saying that when you remove an item from the dock, then open and close it manually, it comes back permanently?

Not permanently in the sense that I can remove the item from the dock again. But when I open it back, I will have to remove it again as it's a recent app at that moment. And again, and again...

Did you try turning off "Recent Items" under *Settings → Desktop & Dock"?

@Allan that's what I did actually as I haven't found any solution to hide specific apps only.
